# Is it possible to pretend to be lower .NET version than it actually is?

Tags: c#

Sharepoint 2010 has a version check in single place (also starting from some update WSS 3.0 has such check also):

```
...
Version version = Environment.Version;
if (version.Major > 2)
{
    ...
    throw new PlatformNotSupportedException(@string);
```

I know, that I should not do this, but just out of curiosity - is it possible to overcome this  without writing huge proxy?

Just out of curiosity, wondering if it is possible to do any of these:

1. adjust this check in sharepoint's dll at runtime to pass (class, that is using it is sealed and internal, if you're curious, it is Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase class in Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll)
2. temporary override Environment.Version return value, something like:

   `using (new EnvironmentVersionOverride("2.0")) {  ...   }`
3. some other way?

Update:
`Environment.Version` decompiled source:

```
public static Version Version
{
  get
  {
    return new Version("4.0.30319.18444");
  }
}
```

Comment: Decompile environment class with DotPeek and check what it uses.

Comment: added decompiled Version property from Environment class.

Comment: *maybe* you could try using `bindingRedirect`s in your app.config and try to run the programm using the old frameworks core (I guess this is where Environment is defined) ... at your own risk with plenty of tests though!

Comment: Do you have any idea *why* SharePoint does this check? Perhaps it has a good reason - or maybe there's an update that removes it?

Comment: I have no idea why they made this change, as long as WSS 3.0 SP2 is working ok with 4.0 .NET and from WSS 3.0 SP3 appread this check, so you would assume, that that later version should better support later framework version, but it is not the case. I guess I saw some blog post, that they simply were limited by time and had no chance to check if everything works with .NET 4.0.

Comment: Why aren't you just compiling your code for .NET 2.0, or whatever is necessary for Sharepoint to be satisfied?

Comment: There are mocking frameworks that are capable of replacing static methods. Also, you could modify the sharepoint assembly using an IL editor. Both of these strike me as bad ideas but I assume you have your reason for asking.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, WSS 3.0/Share Point 2010 were created such that the engineers at Microsoft knew exactly which version of the Common Language Runtime (CLR) WSS 3.0/Share Point 2010 would run against without errors.

As alluded to above, `Environment.Version` returns the CLR version (**not** the .NET Framework Version) currently loaded in your process. There is no way to "fake" or "proxy" this value. If you are running SharePoint on a Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, or Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, then the CLR 2.0 is automatically installed (I'm not sure about Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012, though).

It sounds to me like you need to make sure that the Application Pool in IIS under which the Share Point 2010 (or WSS 3.0) website is running is using .Net Framework Version 2.0.50727 (which implies the use of CLR 2.0). As stated [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/07/14/net-framework-support-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx), Share Point 2010 will simply refuse to run when the website for it is using an Application Pool targeting the .NET Framework 4.0.

If the machine running Share Point 2010 / WSS 3.0 does not have the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 installed (which includes CLR 2.0), installing that and ensuring the Application Pool settings are correct should resolve your issue and you won't need to "proxy" the value of `Environment.Version`.

If you're trying to create a library for use by Share Point 2010, then ensure that your library is targeting .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll as a reference in my web application and there is no way to lower .net version for my application pool, that is hosting my web application. Interestingly enough, this version check appeared in later WSS 3.0 updates, also Sharepoint 2010, if it was in all versions, I would be sure, that WSS is not compatible with .net 4.0 or something, but now if older version is working fine, why on earth they made it incompatible in newer versions.